# Trying to animate knock out text gradient on CodePen

Tags: html, css

This might just be a matter of it not being possible but here is my CodePen link https://codepen.io/Spectral/pen/QgMdbM?editors=1100

I can't make the gradient animate, am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible?

code:

```
    <h1 class='knockout'>This text should be animated!</h1>

    body{background:#fdf}

.knockout{
  margin:50px 0 0 0 auto;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  color:blue;

  /* gradient*/

background: linear-gradient(4deg, #4a6bbd, #b65181, #3c636c);


  /* animation */



-webkit-animation: gradientAnimation 4s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: gradientAnimation 4s ease infinite;
-o-animation: gradientAnimation 4s ease infinite;
animation: gradientAnimation 4s ease infinite;

@-webkit-keyframes gradientAnimation {
    0%{background-position:2% 0%}
    50%{background-position:99% 100%}
    100%{background-position:2% 0%}
}
@-moz-keyframes gradientAnimation {
    0%{background-position:2% 0%}
    50%{background-position:99% 100%}
    100%{background-position:2% 0%}
}
@-o-keyframes gradientAnimation {
    0%{background-position:2% 0%}
    50%{background-position:99% 100%}
    100%{background-position:2% 0%}
}
@keyframes gradientAnimation { 
    0%{background-position:2% 0%}
    50%{background-position:99% 100%}
    100%{background-position:2% 0%}
}
  /* knockout*/
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  font-size:20vw;
  text-align:center;

  /* stroke*/
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: #010;
}
```

Comment: Solved thanks to David C

Answer (score 0):

The `@keyframes {}` block of code must be written outside the `.knockout {}` block of code, rather than within it. Here is an example of the background gradient working:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjJoym?editors=1100

(I removed the @-webkit, @-moz, @-o code to simplify this demonstration)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you were looking for, and its a little complicated, but I just added your code to an existing sample of mine. Maybe you could do something with it, I kinda gave up on it.

https://codepen.io/MikeIke/pen/xrgvEW

```
<div class="header">
<h1>Animated Fixed Knockout Text Example(Work In Progress)</h1>
<h3>Scroll down to see</h3>
</div>
<div id="profile">
  <div class="section">
    <div id="knock1">
      <div id="knock2">
        <div class="sectionTitle" id="profileTitle">TEXT</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```